# Why doesn't Visual Studio's scanf_s() function take string inputs?

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, scanf, c-strings

I use Visual Studio 2022, which marks `scanf()` function as unsafe and deprecates it. It recommends me to use `scanf_s()` instead.
So yesterday my teacher was teaching us strings in C and showed us a program to receive a string from the keyboard which I tried out in my compiler
Using `scanf_s()` to input a string returned error `C4473` or `C6064` even though my code was identical to that of my teacher's aside from the `scanf()` difference.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() {
    char name[25];
    printf("Enter your name ");
    scanf_s("%s", name);//gave an ERROR
    printf("Hello %s!", name);
}
```

I tried using the regular `scanf()` along with disable warning and it worked.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

void main() {
    char name[25];
    printf("Enter your name ");
    scanf("%s", name);//worked as intended
    printf("Hello %s!", name);
}
```

Why does `scanf_s` fail take string inputs?

Comment: It does, but you are missing the size argument. `scanf_s` isn't a direct replacement for `scanf`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are asked to use another function, that does not mean you only need to change the name. It is a different function. You must read the documentation and adjust how you use it. You must provide a length value for strings.

Comment: The C standard has not deprecated `scanf`. It is Microsoft (in their wisdom). I recommend you disable all their MS VC specific warnings and learn to use the standard function correctly , which here should be `scanf("%24s", name);`

Comment: You should copy&paste the error you get. If you use `*scanf` to read a string into a `char` array using format `%s`, you should add a size limitation to the format to avoid writing past the end of the array. To see what happens you can add other variables before and after `name` and enter 80 characters with your example code. The program might crash or overwrite other variables.

Comment: *I use Visual Studio 2022, which marks `scanf()` function as unsafe and deprecates it.*  Don't believe the [vendor-lock-in FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt#Microsoft). Read [this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm): "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard *K.3.5.3.2 The fscanf_s function) This description is the same as for the function `scanf_s`

> 4 The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that the c, s,
> and [ conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless
> assignment suppression is indicated by a *). The first of these
> arguments is the same as for fscanf. That argument is immediately
> followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type
> rsize_t and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by
> the first argument of the pair. If the first argument points to a
> scalar object, it is considered to be an array of one element.

So you need to write

```
scanf_s( "%s", name, sizeof( name ) );
```

Also this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

will be safer if to rewrite it like

```
scanf( "%24s", name );
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: In the `scanf_s`  example I suggest to use `sizeof(name)` instead of `25`. (Unfortunately a similar solution is not so easy with `scanf("%24s", name)`.)

Comment: I note that the C standard says in [Annex K.3.3 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.3p2) that _The header `<stddef.h>` defines a type. The type is `rsize_t` which is the type `size_t`._. I think that means that the `(rsize_t)` cast is not really necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler At first I wrote (rsize_t ) 25. So the casting was left after I changed the record.:)

Comment: Note that `scanf_s( "%s", name, sizeof( name ) );` is a problem with VC which [uses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170) a non-compliant `scanf_s( "%s", name, (unsigned) sizeof( name ) );`